# AngularJS : Bind to transclusive directive without isolating the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Let's say I have some angular markup like:

```
<custom bindTo="modelProperty">
    <!-- Trascluded content. -->
</custom>
```

Would it be possible for the custom directive to bind using the bindTo attribute, allowing the properties to be accessible to the transcluded content, without isolating the scope of custom? Basically, I want a directive to bind to a custom part of the model without cutting it off from the scopes of its parents and without having to add extra code like:

```
scope.prop = scope.$parent.prop;
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I imagine it would be structured something like http://plnkr.co/edit/zq2OO1?p=preview, except working and without the isolate scope.

Comment: I don't think you can't do that without poluting the wrapping scope (e.g. with `bindTo`). And if you polute the wrapping scope, then it will break if there are more than 1 `custom` directives on the page.

Comment: @ExpertSystem I think they should be able to do it if they use `scope:true` and pass that scope into the transclude function as the first argument (check out my answer)

Comment: @MarcKline: Yeah, I meant they can't share the scope. Your approach is fine as long as prototypal inheritance stays out of your way (e.g. you don't need to update a primitive value from the transcluded element). But other than that it is indeed working.

Comment: @ExpertSystem Thanks. Yep, that's why I included the note about making sure they have dots in models (e.g. they are not primitives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `scope: true` you can maintain access to the parent scope's properties via prototypical inheritance while maintaining unique scopes for each instance of the directive (ie. so that it is reusable). (Note: Make sure you observe [the dot rule](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot) for any models you need to change on the parent scope from within the transcluded content)

You'll need to call the `transclude` function from the `compile` function, passing the directive's scope as the first argument in order to link the transcluded content against it.

It might look something like this:

```
.directive('custom', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transclude){ 
      scope.bindTo = scope[attrs.bindTo];
      transclude(scope, function(clone){
        elem.find('ng-transclude').replaceWith(clone);
      });
    },
    template: '<div>From parent scope: <i>{{someVar}}</i> <ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>'
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/AAT0dkLAfZDMb1oAfQj5?p=preview)

Comment: Note that according to the docs, `compile`'s `transclude` **[is deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-compile-)**, so you should use `link`'s `transclude`.

Comment: Hadn't seen that. I just updated my answer and demo to reflect that. Thanks.